# SQLquery to merge multiple row values into single row separated by delimiters &display along with other fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me with the below scenarios.

I have 3 tables where i need to display a single record for one fileno with multiple values of same field should be displayed with delimiters by join all three tables.

OrdersTable (orderguid is Primary key ) and guids are referencing in buyer and property tables
I have 2 address referring same fileno
I have 2 BuyerName referring same fileno

so the o/p should be 
fileno   address1,address2  zip   state  buyername,buyername

Orders Table

```
Orderguid  (PK) fileno          
8C25-00F768 100         
2C25-00D695 200
```

Property Table

```
Address Zip State   OrderGuid(FK)   
Street no 1 122235  TX  8C25-00F768 
Street no 2 122235  TX  8C25-00F768
```

Buyers Table

```
BuyerName   OrderGuid (FK)          
Dennis Richard  8C25-00F768         
Levis Richard   8C25-00F768
```

output :

```
fileno  Address Zip State   BuyerName
100 Street no 1 ; Street no 2   122235  TX  Dennis Richard; Levis Richard
200 null    null    null    null
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY, STRING_AGG().

Comment: What is your SQLServer version? It affects whether we can recommend string_agg or whether it has to be a stuff/for xml path or similar ugliness

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like this :

**EDIT :**  ( I highly recommend to avoid merging multiple values into a single row)

```
    ;WITH CTE AS (



select o.fileno ,
stuff((SELECT ';' + pr.Address from Property pr
inner join Orders o on o.Orderguid=p.Orderguid

 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
) AS Address

,
stuff((SELECT ';' + b.BuyerName from Buyer b
inner join Orders o1 on o1.Orderguid=p.Orderguid

 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
) AS Buyers

,p.Zip
,p.State

 ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.Orderguid ORDER BY o.Orderguid ) rn


from Orders o 
left join Property p ON p.Orderguid=o.Orderguid 
left join Buyer b ON b.Orderguid=p.Orderguid

group by o.fileno, p.Address, p.Zip, p.State,p.Orderguid,o.Orderguid )
select * from CTE
where rn=1
```

[See results from here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=149a31b843bcff91c5decf3029ecc2e4)